# Update a ASP.NET UpdatePanel from the code behind with no ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I know that you can call an update on an UpdatePanel server side by calling the Update function on it. I have done this in the past, though in the past I also had a ContentTemplate.

In one of my current projects I add all of the controls to a the UpdatePanel in the code behind so there is no ContentTemplate defined. Is there a way to update the UpdatePanel from the code behind despite this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

The UpdatePanel definition looks like this, with only place holder, I add a menu, a MultiView and n GridViews to it in the code behind.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel  runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a content template right there.?

Comment: This doesn't work though, I think it's because it's a place holder rather than the controls themselves.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.  Check these out:

- http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/11-Adding-Controls-dynamically-to-UpdatePanel-control-and-Setting-Triggers-Dynamically.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2007/04/05/110888.aspx